# Benefits of moving from `PermitRootLogin without-password` to `PermitRootLogin no`?

Tags: ssh, security

I'm setting up a VPS to host various websites of mine. By default, VPSes created by my VPS host have my public key in their root accounts' `authorized_keys` file, letting me log in as root. There are a few lines in `sshd_config` of note:

```
Port 5502 # Actually not 5502, but definitely not 22
PermitRootLogin without-password
#PasswordAuthentication no
#PermitEmptyPasswords no
```

As I understand things, commented-out lines like the last two merely state defaults.

For many reasons, each website has its own user account. My public key is in each of these user accounts' `authorized_keys` as well. None of these user accounts currently have passwords. Not having passwords for these accounts spares me the hassle of having to manage passwords for these accounts. On the other hand, neither `sudo` (in its default configuration) nor `chsh` work with passwordless accounts.

Incidentally, I use Ansible to automate user-account creation and user-directory setup. All tasks that can be done as a website user are.

My question is this: **compared to allowing only public-key remote login  to the root account, what security benefits would I gain by completely disabling remote login to the root account?**

From what I can tell, if I disable remote root login entirely, I only become better defended against attackers who:

- don't have a copy of my keypair, **and**
- have managed to find a remote exploit in sshd that allows them to log in remotely

As far as I can tell, if an attacker has a copy of my keypair, he *almost certainly* also has access to what username and port to use to connect to my VPS. The only place he'd be able to get my keypair is if he's managed to compromise my desktop or laptop.

Am I missing something from my threat modeling?

Answer (score 2):

For me completely disabling root login make sense if multiple system admins accessing your system.

If no ssh login at all for root, they will be forced to use sudo. Audit purpose it will be useful and can have controls implemented.

Secondly, additional layer of security because an attacker have to findout both a valid user name and its credentials (if it is not root). 'root' user exist in all systems. So they only have to worry about pass/key part of root user to get in.